# Dynamic virtual host setup based on folder structure

Tags: nginx

Considering I have something like this:

```
    /sites/foo/a1
    /sites/foo/a2
    /sites/foo/a3
    /sites/bar/b1
    /sites/bar/b2
```

And I want to access them like this:

```
foo.a1.mydomain.com
```

or (if the last one doesn't work)

```
foo-a1.mydomain.com
```

How can I create virtual hosts dynamically in nginx, to accept going to those folders?

Comment: "I" is always capital case in English.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished by the following nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
    set $path "default";
    if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.([a-z0-9-]+)\.mydomain.com$) {
        set $path "$1/$2";
    }
    root /sites/$path;
}
```

Nginx sets the `$path` variable according to the groupings in the regular expression matched against the `$host` variable, which is automatically set by nginx (see [Embedded Variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables)). By initially setting `$path` to "default", you can serve content from the `/sties/default` directory in the event that `$host` doesn't match the regex.

Alternatively, you can use regex matching in the `server_name` directive. See [Nginx Server Names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more info.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: @peterh, fair enough; edited.